# Firebase Cloud Function "Error: could not handle the request"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I run my cloud function in browser, I see "Error: could not handle the request" message even though it works, and documents get moved in database. Is it what I am supposed to see there? If not, why am I seeing it?

Comment: Can you attach a snippet of the code

Comment: @Taio, here is the code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211715/firebase-cloud-function-questions

Comment: @Taio the issue was solved when I implemented your answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211842/cloud-function-finished-with-status-timeout/57213446#57213446