# Cloud Function finished with status: 'timeout'"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

In Firebase console, the last Event message in Functions/Log section is "Function execution took 60006 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'". Is "timeout" the status the function is supposed to finish with? Or did I miss something in the code that would say "that's the end"?

Comment: Your function didn't terminate correctly within the timeout period.  That's all that can be said with the information you've given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should send a response like `res.send(200)` at the end for it to terminate properly